# Spring Boot MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, spring

I am trying to access my database and return some of the results. I have watched a bunch of tutorials but each one seems to be off. Right now the @Autowired is giving an error of 'No Beans of UserRepository
 type found If anyone could help me it would be greatly appreciated. Here is what I have so far.

Controller

```
package com.rdopler.ecommerceTest.controller;
import java.util.*;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
@RequestMapping(path="/user")
public class UserController {

    @Autowired
    UserRepository userRepository;
    @GetMapping
    public String check() {
        return "Welcome";
    }
@GetMapping(path="/getusernames")
    public List<String>getAllUserNames() {

        return userRepository.getAllUserNames();

    }
}
```

Repo

```
package com.rdopler.ecommerceTest.repository;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import java.util.*;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public class UserRepository {
    @Autowired
    JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;
    public List<String> getAllUserNames() {

        List<String> usernameList = new ArrayList<>();
        usernameList.addAll(jdbcTemplate.queryForList("select * from employees ", String.class);
        return usernameList;
    }
}
```

application.properties

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/storeDB?useUnicode=true&useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=*****
```

Main:

```
package com.rdopler.ecommerceTest;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class EcommerceTestApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(EcommerceTestApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

Comment: Could you share your application main?

Comment: I updated main for you.

Comment: Shouldn't UserRepository be an interface that extends JpaRepository or CrudRepository or at the very minimum `Repository`? Did you even bother to read the documentation? https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-commons/docs/1.6.1.RELEASE/reference/html/repositories.html

Comment: @jbx There's no requirement for a repository to be an interface, or to extend JpaRepository, nor CrudRepository.  Not everyone wants to use Spring Data.   The OP's approach is perfectly valid, especially for beginners exploring Spring & Spring Boot.

Comment: Ryan I am curious that UserController references UserRepository (in a different package) but there's no import for UserRepository.  Can you double check that you don't accidentally have two UserRepository classes, one in controller and one in repository?

Answer (score 0):

Try by adding @EnableJpaRepositories("packagename") 
in main class.

Answer (score 0):

In your main app try adding this annotation below @SpringBootApplication

```
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.rdopler.ecommerceTest")
```

It will help you to scan all your components. Also if you have any service(s) in your application, make sure you annotate that/those with @Service annotation.

Answer (score -1):

Add @Component to the class UserRepository

Comment: This is not necessary because `@Repository` is already a `@Component`.

Answer (score -1):

add @Transactional in UserRepository,
also, add @ComponentScan in main class.